# Eclipse Core Expressions object properties

Tags: eclipse

So, I have a core expression. It has a `with` element that retrieves my variable (successfully). Say my variable is of type `java.awt.Point`; thus it has two public properties, `x` and `y`. Is there any way to test against these properties in a core expression?

If there was some way I could provide my own implementation of `org.eclipse.core.expressions.Expression`, that would work. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by creating a [propertyTester](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_expressions_propertyTesters.html) that would react properly to your variable using your custom code.